# Android Kotlin - onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() will finish my activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, onbackpressed

When `onBackPressed()` not working in recent sdk, we have to use the new method
`onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()`.

But my question is

> will it finish my activity?

Or, I have to **callback** the `onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()` to finish my activity?

**Button code is :**

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
}
```

**CallBack Code:**

```
onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object: OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        finish()
    }
})
```

Comment: You should never call either of these functions in the first place because of possible unwanted side effects and behavior differences between Android versions. None of the `on…` functions are intended to be called by anything but the OS. They are only for overriding to add behaviors. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you want to finish your activity, just call `finish()` directly.

Comment: That's good. But suppose my app have a button which have to behave like the back button. Then I must call onBackPressed(), don't I?

Comment: You can send a back button press to the OS with `activity.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))`.

Comment: `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` is not supported anymore as well as per https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/predictive-back-gesture: "This update provides a migration path for back navigation APIs that are no longer being supported, which are KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK and any classes with onBackPressed methods such as Activity and Dialog."

Comment: The question is quite valid as Google didn't yet discuss the impact of predictive back gesture on `Activity.finish()`. I actually don't see how they should both work in hand in hand, as `finish()` will finish the Activity at once, so no way for the user to revert (this is what predictive back allows while the user is still dragging). Consequently `Activity.finish()` would have to be deprecated as well - which of course would mean a big gotcha for many apps. Many (some valid!) navigation shortcuts just would cease to work.

Comment: And yes, I recognize that Google states that "Deep linking simulates manual navigation"  - but let's be realistic: it's not what most users would expect (at least not in all situations). ‍♂️ I think it's a similar problem like the Up vs Back controversy. There is the official interpretation (which includes that Up should never close the app) and there is the expectation of users where Up and Back are virtually always perceived as the same and you get weird looks if they do different things (although it might be the right thing to do as per the guidelines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is :

> onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() will finish my activity

Luckily **onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()** have destroyed my activity.
I don't need to callback the **OnBackPressedCallback** object to finish() my activity.

Here is the checking code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    ...

    btnBack?.setOnClickListener { onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() }

    //onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        //override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            //finish() // No Longer Needs to Callback and Finish
        //}
    //})

}


override fun isFinishing(): Boolean {
    println("Finishing")
    return super.isFinishing()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    println("Destroyed & Finished")
}
```